# Understand Sencha Touch syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I have gone through dev.sencha.com and while I do understand Javascript/jQuery, I do not understand the syntax followed in Sencha Touch or ExtJS.

Could you please give a general idea with an example of what or how the syntax works..Also how exactly should one think when trying to integrate Sencha touch into a HTML/CSS web app ? Also any analogy to jQuery ?

Comment: give us an example of the syntax you do not understand.  SenchaTouch apps ARE webapps.  They run in the browser

Comment: Question is very vague... Which part are you having difficulties with? Which tutorials have you looked at?

Comment: I am a beginner for Sencha Touch and have gone through their official pages. But while they provide the output for any code with examples, they do not actually explain the individual parts of the code..Something which I feel should be required when editing any code..So i wanted to get a general idea about the coding style in Sencha Touch..e.g. Jquery is mainly based on CSS for coding..similarly jow does it work in Sencha Touch?

Comment: Sencha touch and jQuery are worlds apart. Here's an example of extending a panel to load views inside of itself and provide a back button for navigation. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/src/index.js 
Maybe you can ask a more detailed question referring to this file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sencha Touch is Javascript. It is written in JS there is very little magic in the library. If you understand JS you should be able to understand Sencha Touch.

Sencha Touch and JQuery are very different ways of approaching the same problem.  Sencha Touch uses Object Oriented programming concepts much more than jQuery does. As well, there are things that are very similar.  After working in jQuery for such a long time you need to have a open mind when approaching other Javascript libraries as there are different concepts that jQuery does not follow.

Also the libraries are targeting different 'niches'.  I would say that Sencha Touch is more of a MVC library, containing UI widgets (like jQuery UI), with multiple data abstractions (ORM-lite, syncronizing) and happens to have DOM manipulation. jQuery is mostly DOM manipulation.

Where jQuery and Sench Touch are the same:

jQuery

```
$('#mydiv').addClass('highlighted').css({'background-color': red'});
```

Sencha Touch:

```
Ext.select('#mydiv').addCls('highlighted').applyStyles({'background-color': red'});
```

jQuery

```
$.get('someurl', 'get', function(){ console.log("Success")})
```

Sencha Touch

```
Ext.Ajax.request({'url': 'someurl', 
  method: 'get', 
  success: function(){ console.log('success')})
```

So you can see that there are ways of performing similar tasks in both of the libraries.

However things you can't do in jQuery. Like create a full browser window that has a carousel in it.
Sencha Touch:

```
var panel = Ext.Panel({
   dockedItems: [ {xtype: 'toolbar', title: 'Sample Toolbar', dock: 'top' } ]
   items: [ {xtype: 'carousel', items: [
             {html: 'card 1'},
             {html: 'card 2'}]
   ],
   fullscreen: true
});
panel.show();
```

Instead of looking online at their demos, which I agree can be pretty confusing, I would recommend watching their introductory [videos](http://vimeo.com/12636777) on their [vimeo channel](http://vimeo.com/sencha) and take a look at their examples in their downloaded source code.

Comment: Mind boggling answer..could not have expected anything better than this ! You have understood right..I have jQuery exp and while I do understand under the hood they are similar, I want to understand the sencha touch approach, compared to jQuery..u have explained it beautifully..Finally, u definitely stand out from the responses given above..A++..Deserves atleast 1000 votes..

Comment: Just had 1 question if u could answer - like how do i test Sencha youch examples locally..like on a web server like Apache..I know u have already answered the main question..So only if u could..otherwise it's fine as well..

Comment: I would recommend use Chrome to view the html file that contains your source.  You can either open the file locally, or set up apache to serve the static document.  You don't need any extra apache modules, as it is just plain HTML. If you are working locally you have to be aware that AJAX won't typically work due to Cross Domain Policies.

Comment: Ok..I'll use Chrome and test the local files directly..Thx again for all ur help..Deserves 1000+ votes here..